# Last option is getting selected as default in HTML

Tags: html

In my form, the last option is getting selected as default. How can avoid this?

```
   <form action=" url " method=" post">         
        <h3>Question</h3>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="option1" checked> option1<br>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="option2" checked>option2<br>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="option3" checked>option3<br>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="option4" checked>option4<br>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="option5" checked> option5<br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Answer">
   </form>
```

I want select none of the radio buttons at the start.

Comment: Please [learn to love labels](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200711/use_the_label_element_to_make_your_html_forms_accessible/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove checked attribute from all the inpputs

```
<input type="radio" name="choice" value="option1"> option1<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

> In my form, the last option is getting selected as default.

You've `checked` **every** one of your radio buttons, but only one in a group can be checked.

Error recovery is checking the last one.

> How can avoid this?

Check only the one you want to be checked.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#submit').click(function(){
  if(typeof $('input[name=choice]:checked', '#myForm').val()=="undefined"){
    alert("please select oiption");
  }else{
    alert($('input[name=choice]:checked', '#myForm').val());
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form id="myForm" action=" url " method=" post">         
        <h3>Question</h3>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="option1" > option1<br>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="option2" >option2<br>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="option3" >option3<br>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="option4" >option4<br>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" value="option5" > option5<br>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit Answer">
   </form>
```